# In R how do I remove empty rows from a data frame and extract one value from a cell and paste it in other cell?

Tags: r

How do I remove the empty rows from the following data frame?
Can you also tell me how to extract the data from row 11 column "positive" (417) and paste it in row 13 column "positive"?

```
    district    positive
9   Thiruvananthapuram  386
10      
11      417
12      
13  Kollam  
14      
15      
16  Pathanamthitta  493
17      
18      
19  Alappuzha   364
20      
21      
22  Kottayam    477
23      
24      
25  Idukki  107
26      
27      
28      
29  Ernakulam   602
30      
31      
32      
33  Thrissur    436
34      
35      
36  Palakkad    226
37      
38      
39  Malappuram  511
40      
41      
42  Kozhikode   452
43      
44  Wayanad 174
45      
46  Kannur  266
47      
48      
49  Kasaragod   80
50      
51  Total   4991
```

I have tried drop_na, na.mit etc... but nothing worked at this stage.

Following is the script that I have being using?

```
location <-  'https://health.kerala.gov.in/bullattin/january21/english/January-01.pdf'
out <- extract_tables(location, pages = c(2:6))
temp <- data.frame(out[[4]])
temp1 <- temp %>% dplyr::select(X1, X2)
temp2 <- temp1[-c(1:8), ]
head <- c('district', 'positive')
colnames(temp2) <- head
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of rows containing any NAs, try complete.cases():

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

As for your second question, I’m not sure whether you want to leave row 11 unchanged or not but if you do:

```
df[13,2] <- df[11,2]
```

Comment: thank you, to get rid of empty rows, i have used filter.